# How to align item to center using Ant Design PageHeader?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I've been trying to center a bunch of buttons in a NavBar using the Ant Design framework.

**NavBar.tsx**

```
const NavBar: React.FC<NavBarProps> = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <PageHeader
      style={{
        display: flex,
        align-items: center, //Doesn't work.
        backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5"
      }}
      backIcon={
        <Icon theme="twoTone" style={{ fontSize: "32px" }} type="skin"></Icon>
      }
      onBack={() => null}
      title={
        <Title style={{ margin: "0px" }} level={1}>
          Athena.
        </Title>
      }
      extra={[
        <RegularButton size="large" icon="shopping-cart">
          Cart.
        </RegularButton>,
        <RegularButton size="large" icon="profile">
          Profile.
        </RegularButton>
      ]}
    />
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

However if i edit the child element through inspect-element, it works.

```
.ant-page-header-heading {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

[image]

^ Buttons are floating to the top instead of being middle aligned.

How can I target the child element using the `style` props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I target the child element using the `style` props?

You can't, refer to [`Style Prop`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

Therefore, you need to target the CSS-selector as normal or with CSS-in-JS.

Check the [Styling FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html).

```
// index.css
.ant-page-header-heading {
  background: paleturquoise;
}

// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { PageHeader } from 'antd';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const HeaderColoredContent = styled(PageHeader)`
  .ant-page-header-content {
    background-color: palevioletred;
  }
`;

// v Will apply both styles.
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <HeaderColoredContent
      ...
    </HeaderColoredContent>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

[image]

[image: Edit Q-58470177-StyleCSSSelector]